# Is it possible to install the Web Deployment Handler (WMSVC) on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, msdeploy

I would like to install the Web Deployment Handler service on my development machine (Windows 7 with IIS7) for test purposes, but according to the documentation on MSDN (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722796(WS.10).aspx) it seems like it can only be installed on Windows Server 2008 with IIS7.

Anyone knows of a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to install WMSVC in client SKUs (service wont work), only Server SKUs support it.

However, you should be able to install the Web Deploy Service which will give you almost all functionality except delegated administration, so only administrators can connect to it.